# how to display uploaded images in order using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have the code that automatically displays images that uploaded. The problem I am having is that the pictures are displayed in alphabetical order. I want them to be displayed according to upload time, the newest picture is on top and oldest on bottom.

This is the code i have.

default.aspx.cs:

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
        List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());

        foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
        {
            if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item) != "Thumbs.db")
            {
               images.Add(String.Format("~/Images/{0}"System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
            }
        }

        RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
        RepeaterImages.DataBind();
```

default.aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image" class="image" runat="server" height="250" width="250" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' /></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your filesInDirectory to a list of FileInfo objects, then order them by your chosen date. (Syntax approx)

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
var files = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach (var str in filesInDirectory)
{
  files.Add(new FileInfo(str));
}

foreach (var file in files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime))
{
  //image handling
}
```

Comment: what am i supposed to put in image handling?

Comment: The if inside your original foreach.

Comment: the foreach loop is not mandatory...you can just pass the list item into the view and do the iteration in the view itself